# how to keep worksheet.visible = false and still get data like activesheet name and cell address

Tags: excel, vba, hide

I have a list of excel file names and those file's path in 2 columns. Using the code , I open each worksheet at a time , search for a specific keyword in opened workbook , wherever match is found. I have to get that workbook name (already have) , matched found cell address , that active sheet name and value in cell.

Query 1:
Now , already have code with me it works properly but when I hide the excel sheets so that user can't see them , the ActiveSheet  can't be used code does not go to opened workbook instead it search in macro file , In simple words if I hide files using .visible = false it does not work , it search values in macro. Please help to fix it

Query 2:
I think the code to paste value in macro is not 100% accurate , because I have just mentioned sheets not workbook , please help to make it solid

Query 3:
How to make it faster if I want to search 10k files

I have tried the below code

```
  Dim lastvalueoffiles As Integer  


  lastvalueoffiles = Sheet4.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row


For EachFileinPath = 2 To lastvalueoffiles

    Dim wb As Workbook
    'wb.Visible = False

    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Sheet4.Cells(EachFileinPath, 2).Value)
   ActiveWindow.Visible = True
    
          Dim SearchString As String
          Dim SearchRange As Range, cl As Range
          Dim FirstFound As String
          Dim sh As Worksheet
 
     '''Set Search value
     SearchString = Sheet1.Cells(6, 8).Value
    
           Application.FindFormat.clear
    
           '''loop through all sheets
    
    For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        
        ''' Find first instance on sheet
        Set cl = sh.Cells.Find(What:=SearchString, After:=sh.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
        
        sh.Activate
        
        If Not cl Is Nothing Then
            ' if found, remember location
            FirstFound = cl.Address
            ' format found cell
            
            Do
                        
               LastValueoftheresultfound = Sheet4.Cells(EachFileinPath, ActiveSheet.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
                   
                momo = ActiveCell.Address
                
                ActiveSheet.Select
                
                
                Sheet4.Cells(EachFileinPath, LastValueoftheresultfound + 1).Value = ActiveSheet.Name
                
                Sheet4.Cells(EachFileinPath, LastValueoftheresultfound + 2).Value = cl.Address
                
                Sheet4.Cells(EachFileinPath, LastValueoftheresultfound + 3).Value = cl.Value
                
                '''cl.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
                
                Set cl = sh.Cells.FindNext(After:=cl)
                ' repeat until back where we started
            Loop Until FirstFound = cl.Address
        End If
    Next

ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False

koko = Sheet1.Cells(6, 8).Value
    
Next EachFileinPath
```

Comment: `cl.worksheet.name` will give you the name of the sheet.

Comment: You don't need to select/activate the sheets or the cells. I recommend reading [How to avoid using select](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23913882/16578424).

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly....

Before running the macro, sheet4 look something like this:
[image]

test1.xlsx sheet1 cell H6 value is aaa
test1.xlsx sheet2 cell A1 value is aaa
test1.xlsx sheet3 cell B1:B2 value is aaa
test1.xlsx sheet4 cell C1:C3 value is aaa

test2.xlsx, the cells are the same, but value is bbb
test3.xlsx, the cells are the same, but value is ccc.

Expected result (please ignore the fill color)
[image]

```
Sub test()
Dim shTrg As Worksheet, rg As Range, FL As String, OpenedWB As Workbook
Dim SearchString As String, sh As Worksheet, cl As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set shTrg = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet4") 'change if needed
Set rg = shTrg.Range("B2", shTrg.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)) 'change if needed
Application.FindFormat.Clear

For Each FL In rg
    Set OpenedWB = Workbooks.Open(FL)
    SearchString = OpenedWB.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(6, 8).Value
    For Each sh In OpenedWB.Worksheets
        Set cl = sh.Cells.Find(What:=SearchString, After:=sh.Cells(1, 1), _
            LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
        If Not cl Is Nothing Then
            FirstFoundAddress = cl.Address
            Do
                With shTrg.Cells(FL.Row, shTrg.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1)
                .Resize(1, 3).Value = Array(sh.Name, cl.Address, cl.Value)
                End With
                Set cl = sh.Cells.FindNext(cl)
            Loop Until FirstFoundAddress = cl.Address
        End If
    Next sh
    OpenedWB.Close SaveChanges:=False
Next FL

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
End Sub
```

Please note that the sub may throw an error if the count of the found cells in the OpenedWorkbook exceed than the last column of the shTrg.